# How to make method reference in attribute parameter

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I want to make an attribute that will allow me to specify some method applied to property, like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [MyAttribute(Converter="ConverterMethod")]
    public string Prop { get; set; }

    public static string ConverterMethod(string src)
    {
        return src + " converted";
    }
}
```

What is the 'right' way to do that?

Here are the ways that I see:

1. Make string property and extract corresponding method with reflection during runtime
2. Make `Dictionary<string, Func<string, string>>` and populate it with corresponding methods during runtime. Then extract method using attribute's string property as a key. This method is more resistant to refactoring, if I rename method everything will work (dictionary key will remain the same though)
3. Make 'IConverter' interface and pass `typeof(ConverterImpl)` to attribute. Then create an instance of converter during runtime and use its interface to convert values. This way seem the best to me but I never used `Type` properties in attributes and don't even know if they are serialized well.

Which approach is best? Is there other approaches? How people usually do such things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first option is pretty normal, and has the advantage of simplicity. You are right to say the it is a little susceptible to refactoring, but... this is rarely a "real" problem.

Another (fourth) approach, however, would be to make the attribute abstract with an abstract method, and subclass it with the conversion code in the attribute - then at runtime you can get the attribute (as the base-attribute) and just call the virtual method, this approach s common in things like MVC.

Personally, I usually just use the first option, along with unit tests for safety (in case of refactoring etc).